# why after pop_back() operation it still prints the complete vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following main program that creates a Stack object, fills it with integers and then pops them. The code files fine, but the pop_back() part does not seem to work,  even after pop_back() it prints all values. How is this possible?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    vector<int> myVector; //initalization

    int value;
    //input in a vector using push_back
    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
        cin >> value;
        myVector.push_back(value);
    }
    cout<<"Initial vector size:" << myVector.size() <<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
        cout << myVector[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    myVector.pop_back();
    cout<<"Vector size after pop back: " << myVector.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "First element is: " << myVector.front() << endl;
    cout << "Last element is : " << myVector.back() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
        cout << myVector[i];
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're accessing invalid memory on the last iteration. That's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone has focused on saying `this is undefined behavior fix code`, but question was why it works.

To understand why it works you must understand how `vector` works more or less.

- Vector allocates some block of memory to store items.
- size of this block is defined by [capacity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), which says how many items can be stored in vector, without allocating new block of memory
- `capacity` is usually bigger then `size` of the `vector`
- now when you remove items form vector, `capacity` and allocated block of memory doesn't change. This is an optimization.
- when you remove item from back just destructor is called (for `int` it does nothing) and size of vector is reduced.
- your value is not cleared just marked as out of vector size
- so when you use `operator[]` it doesn't check if you exceed its size. It just returns value at specific adders
- since `pop_back` just reduced size you value is still there

Note if you call [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after `pop_back` there is a great chance it will and with crash or you will not receive same value. Still this is undefined behavior and anything can happen.

Another way to see your code is bad is to use `at` which checks if index is in valid range.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` to try to reduce capacity from 6 to 5 probably won't do anything on most implementations. Capacity is likely to remain at least 6.

Comment: This answer explains why OP saw the result they got. But it's important to understand that because this is UB, the behavior may change at any time for no apparent reason. The part about "the value is still there" is not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector::pop_back` function works just fine. After you perform a call to it, you try to print all 6 values instead of 5. Therefore, you are accessing **invalid memory**. In your case, program prints out the value that was removed but in some other case it could print some garbage value. That's why this is UB - **Undefined Behavior**.

Try the following and you will see that last element is not in the `std::vector`:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << myVector[i];
}
```

or, even better, use [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
for (auto const i : myVector) {
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you loop through the vector - you are expecting it to have 6 elements even after you have removed the last element. This is undefined behavior.

Using a range based for would be preferred in both cases where you want to output the contents of the vector:

```
for (auto i:myVector) {
    cout << i;
}
```